# Measuring "mixtureness" of labeled data (python)

Tags: python, prediction

I have some 2D data:

[image]

The data is labeled and shown in different colors. Definitely a non supervised process will not yield any correct prediction because the data is pretty mixed (although the colors seem to have regions of preference). I want to see if it is possible to measure how mixed are points from different sets.

For this I need to define a measurement of how mixed they are (I think that this should exist). Also it would be nice to have these algorithms implemented. I am also looking for a simple predictive model that can be trained used the data shown. Thanks for your help. If possible I'm looking for these implementations in python.

Comment: You could try to create something like 5 clusters using KMeans or something else, and then measure how many cases were "mislabeled," based on the labels shown above.

Comment: @not_a_robot I have used KMeans for doing unsupervised prediction. Is there a way of "telling" the algorithm (in some python module) the initial centroids of the clusters? Cheers!

Comment: I believe you can specify these initial centroids with the `init` parameter in `sklearn.cluster.KMeans`. Then you can look at the intersection of the sets of cluster labels and initial labels.